# Django: How do I call a model function in views that accesses form data and stores the result in the database?

Tags: python, django, database, forms, view

I am a beginner in Django. I am developing an app in Django. I need to store the result of a form in the database, and call a function in views, and then store the result of that function in my database again.
In models.py, this is my model class with the calculate function:

```
class f1New(models.Model):
    v1 = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    u1 = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    a1 = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    t1 = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    def calculate(v1,u1,a1,t1):
        v1 = u1 + a1
```

In views.py,

```
def f1(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = f1Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            f1.calculate(form[v1],form[u1],form[a1],form[t1])
            return question_list(request)
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        print ("Not Post")
    return render_to_response('question_list.html', {'form': form}, context)
```

I do not know if this is correct, and don't know how to check it. 
Any help would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Your view function's name and model name is same.. So this snippet with throw an error

Comment: If you have need to calculate `v1` by adding `u1` and `a1`, then why are you accepting it in form in first place?

Comment: I need to perform advanced calculations based on the values the users input into the box. I was just doing a basic add operation to see if it works.

Comment: Apart from all the invalid syntax in this question, what exactly do you think would not work?

Comment: What exactly is invalid?

Comment: Also, I think the function wouldn't calculate and change the value of v1. Also, if it's doing the same, how do I check?

Comment: For a start: conflict between view and model name; accessing form data via dict lookup; not accepting `self` in a model method; not doing anything with the result of the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea what you are asking here. As Rajesh comments, if `v1` is always calculated from the other elements, why are you accepting it in the form at all?

It's *possible* that you are after this:

```
class F1Model(models.Model):
    ...
    def calculate(self):
        self.v1 = self.u1 + self.a1

class F1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ('v1',)

def f1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = F1Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            f1instance = form.save(commit=False)
            f1instance.calculate()
            f1instance.save()
            return redirect('question_list')
    else:
        form = F1Form()
    return render(request, 'question_list.html', {'form': form})
```

but it's impossible to tell for sure.

Comment: I am using this to make a quiz. The formula is v = u + a.t, so based on whatever values the user enters I calculate the unknown variable. So I need variables for all of them. I want to display the result or see if what I am doing is working, how do I do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You display things by passing their values to a template.

Comment: I have a webpage with a question and divs. I drag values from the question and put it into the divs. Using JS I create hidden input fields that store the same values as the divs. Then I POST the form data using a submit button on the page.
Now, using the values dragged which have been stored in the form, I need to perform a calculation and display the result of the calculation beside the submit button. 
Is my question somewhat clearer now?